# Hazelcast serializer/deserializer

Tags: serialization, hazelcast, in-memory-database, kryo, in-memory-data-grid

How to configure serializer/deserializer at the cluster level. I am able to set the serializer/deserializer at client level using the following Java code.

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
SerializerConfig userDataSerializer = new
SerializerConfig().setTypeClass(UserData.class).setImplementation(new
UserDataSerializer()); clientConfig.getSerializationConfig().addSerializerConfig(userDataSerializer);
```

But while make SQL query it's throwing following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: There is no suitable de-serializer for type 2. This exception is likely to be caused by differences in the serialization configuration between members or between clients and members.
```

Above error is happening because the Hazelcast cluster does not know how to serializer/deserializer the object.

I am using a custom serializer using Kryo to serialize (based on this blog http://blog.hazelcast.com/comparing-serialization-methods/)

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

In the cluster, each node needs to know the serializer/de-serializer to perform the Predicate/SQLPredicate. For that, the required serializer class (as a Java jar file) should be present in start command Java CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a query, the server-side of the cluster will need to be able to de-serialize the object.

The serialization mechanism on the server-side has to match the client-side to work ; so helpfully here you can use the same on both.

As you need to do is extend the `Config` on the server-side in the same way as you extend the `ClientConfig` on the client-side.

[This](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/master/serialization/protobuf-serializer/src/main/java/Member.java#L21) is roughly what you want.

Comment: Yes. You are right that I need to configure server about the serialization/de-serialization and you have provided me an example too. But that example is for the embedded topology. I want to do the same for the separate cluster setup where my client is connected. Could you please help me in configuring the serializer/deserializer on cluster setup?

Comment: The serialization config on the server is the same for both topologies. Whether you use the server in client/server or embedded doesn't affect the mechanism for the server deserializing.